# Why does GROUP_CONCAT + DISTINCT triggers a Out of memory (Needed 8388580 bytes) on some servers?

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, group-concat

I have a live server that doesn't seem to like the GROUP_CONCAT + DISTINCT combination.

Here is a test query

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM site_content
WHERE  type = 'document'
```

The same query seems fine on my localhost(AMPPS) but not on live servers running php 5.2/5.3 with Software version: 5.1.40-community-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Is DISTINCT not supported by this mysql version or is there something else going on?

If I remove DISTINCT everything seems fine but in some cases the values in the comma separated list can be duplicates. I can either remove the duplicates by using DISTINCT or use php's array_unique later which is not ideal.

Thank you

## UPDATE

I created a test table with 4 entries

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a_table` (
  `anId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anotherId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`anId`,`anotherId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

DATA in table is
    1:2
    1:3
    1:4
    2:1

The query I run in phpMyAdmin(but same thing happens in code)

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT anotherId SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM a_table
WHERE  anId = 1
```

error is

5 - Out of memory (Needed 8388580 bytes)

Comment: How big is the table? (Depending on your server configuration, GROUP_CONCAT is only going to show the first X characters of that operation anyway.)

Comment: In order to implement `DISTINCT`, it first has to collect all the values, then remove the duplicates. That temporary value may be too big.

Comment: I tried it on a table with 2 INT columns and 53 entries. Bt it seems to happen for any type of data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqld needed a restart. Possibly something got stuck because of bad query.

Thank you